# 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' AnimationFrame

Tags: javascript

im trying create a class, that can start this game, as a method of my class Game. As you can see i add my request animation frame as a function inside a method, but it give me a error: 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'

```
function Game(){
    this.player = null;
    this.anim = null;
}

Game.prototype.start = function () {
    this.anim = requestAnimFrame( this.start() );
    //code
}

Game.prototype.end = function() {
    cancelAnimFrame ( this.anim );
}

//create game
var game = new Game();

//start game
game.start();
```

This work if I use this :

```
function render(){ 
    requestAnimFrame(render);
};
//start anim
render();
```

So I dont know what it doesnt work if is inside a method.

this is the code for anim frame I use:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
        function(callback,element){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

window.cancelAnimFrame = (function(){  
return  window.cancelAnimationFrame       || 
        window.mozCancelAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback,element){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();
```

Im not use if you know what im trying to do, thanks.

Comment: Game.prototype.start = function () {
    this.anim = requestAnimFrame( this.start() );
    //code
}  looks like an infinite loop, that's probably why it breaks.

Comment: `requestAnimFrame` expects **function** whereas you pass returning value of  function. You have to replace `requestAnimFrame(this.start())` with `requestAnimFrame(this.start)`.

Comment: but the request anim frame is a loop right?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, the problem is that when I call :'this.start' im refering of 'window' as 'this', so the the problem goes if I save it as 'that' or 'window', then excecute it, thanks all.

```
var Game = function () {
    this.anim = null;

}

Game.prototype.startAnimation = function(){
    window.requestAnimFrame(this.startAnimation.bind(this));
}

var game = new Game();
game.startAnimation();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Game.prototype.start = function () {
    this.anim = requestAnimFrame( this.start() );
    //code
}
```

For `requestAnimFrame( this.start() );`, you are calling the start within itself, which causes an infinite loop.

You should try `requestAnimFrame(this.start);` even if it would still looks weird :(.

Comment: oh, i see but how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, but there you'll call the start method of your game instance each x seconds, because each time a requestAnimFrame will call its callback the start will be called and then another requestAnimFrame  will be triggered, and so on.

Comment: function render(){ 
    requestAnimFrame(render); 
  };
render();

Comment: that work, but im trying to implement it on a Method

Comment: I try your code, but it give me another error : 'Failed to execute 'requestAnimationFrame' on 'Window': The callback provided as parameter 1 is not a function.'